# Matching table alias

Tags: regex, alias

I want to create a regex that recognize table with an alias. I can have both

```
table_name AS alias
table_name alias
```

I tried with this

```
^(.*?)\s*(?:as|\s)\s*(.*?)$
```

and it actually works, except the case when the alias starts with 'as'.

Working demos: https://regex101.com/r/jX3tK0/1, https://regex101.com/r/wU0dF8/1

Not working demo: https://regex101.com/r/tY8bK8/1

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the cardinality you chose. The following one should suit your needs:

```
^(.*?)\s+(?:as\s+)?(.*?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/27W3hXKWFYZFvB3m)

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's faster than the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can require a word boundary (`\b`) after the `as`:

```
^(.*?)\s*(?:as\b|\s)\s*(.*?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/tY8bK8/2

Alternatively, you could do [this](https://regex101.com/r/tY8bK8/4#javascript):

```
^(.*?)(?:(\s+as)?\s)\s*(.*?)$
```